# "List object not callable"

Tags: python, list, maya, callable

I'm currently writing a Python based tool for Maya. I'm using a line of code which I have used in countless other sections of other tools, and for some reason it refuses to work this time round. I cannot see any reason why it isn't.

```
def generateClothSkeleton(cloth):
print "Generating Cloth Skeleton"
objects = cmds.textScrollList("clothList", ai=True, q=True)
for x in range(0, len(objects)):
    numVerts = cmds.polyEvaluate((objects[x]), v=True)
    vertPosList = []
    for y in xrange(1, numVerts):
        object = objects[x]
        xformString = object + ".vtx[" + str(y) + "]"
        vertPos = cmds.xform(xformString, t=True, ws=True, a=True, q=True)
        vertPosList.extend([vertPos])
...
```

When run, Python returns an error on the *object = objects[x]* line: *'list' object is not callable*. Which is odd, considering there's no call being made...

Any ideas what's causing this infuriating issue?

EDIT: Its worth noting, that if I run *print objects[x]*, it returns the name of the object as expected...

Comment: Please provide the actual traceback message.  Copy and past it, properly formatted.   The whole traceback stack is very important.

Comment: Are you sure the error is being thrown on that line?  As it is, this won't run because of an indentation error.  The method body needs to be indented.

Comment: Also, just for kicks, I'll mention that `object` is a very important name that you probably shouldn't overwrite.

Comment: Also just for kicks, I'll mention that `print` statements don't return anything, and if `print objects[x]` prints an object name, then your variable names are confusing; try something more meaningful, like `object_names` and `object_name`. By the way, are you sure that the code that you are actually running doesn't have `object = objects(x)` ?

Comment: Please edit your code so you aren't using object/objects as a variable name

Comment: The issue, as others have said, is probably that you're overwriting `object`. (don't do that)

Comment: @recursive - the code is correctly indented, it just was lost in the transfer to S.O (an oversight on my part in formatting)

Comment: @John Machin/Senderle/Dhaivat Pandya/Sri Raghavan - I've tried running the code with different variable names with no success. It still returns the error.

Comment: Bizarrely, if I run the script in an older version of Maya (2011, instead of 2012) the error doesn't appear. Its clearly just an issue with that version of Maya. Since I don't need it to be specifically compatible with 2012, I'll just stick with using 2011.

Comment: Unreladed note: change vertPosList.extend([vertPos]) into .append(), might be a little bit faster.

Comment: You should file a bug on Maya 2012, to help other users.

Answer (score 9):

This Question has sat out for a long time unanswered, so I'll try to help anyone trying to solve a similar problem. Given the passage of time and the fact that you didn't post a stack-trace or format your code properly, I'll ignore that you're indicating a particular line of your code is responsible for the error.
First I'll demonstrate some code that raises this error, and explain why.

```
>>> a_list = []
>>> a_list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

This error is raised because the variable a_list points to a specific empty list in memory. The list object itself isn't callable. Callable means you can execute it like a function or class constructor (or an object that has implemented the `__call__` magic method, rather uncommon). You don't execute an actual list.

The proper way to add on a single item to a list is with append (I see you're wrapping an item in a list and then using the extend method, which is not the straightforward way to do it, and thus likely less efficient.)

```
>>> a_list.append('foo')
```

We can retrieve that item with an index:

```
>>> a_list[0]
'foo'
```

A common early mistake for new Python learners (or experts typing too quickly) is to use parentheses instead of brackets, and we see we get the same error.

```
>>> a_list(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

In an interpreter, this is caught quickly, but there is likely something in Maya that is not executed until it runs your code, and so this issue was never caught.

Another possibility, I see that you're overwriting the builtin `object`. You get a similar error if you attempt to call an instantiated object.

```
>>> an_object = object()
>>> an_object()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'object' object is not callable
```

So, I wonder if perhaps you've overwritten a list constructor, like the builtin `list`, or perhaps `cmds.textScrollList`. If that may be the case, look through your code for any possible cases where you're assigning a list like this:

```
list = ['foo', 'bar'] # Don't do this!!!
```

fix it, and restart your Python session.

---

As a counter example to help you understand calling a list, it *can* (but shouldn't) be implemented.

To actually make a `list` object callable, subclass it and implement a `__call__` method (again, you probably shouldn't do it in production code), in this case we extend the list with the arguments we pass to the list:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.extend(args)

>>> a_list = MyList(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
>>> a_list('ham', 'spam', 'eggs', 'spam')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'ham', 'spam', 'eggs', 'spam']
```

Don't do this.